# Exploding dataset with list of symbols and their own occurrences

Tags: python, pandas

I've this very small dataset

```
import pandas as pd
d = {'Text': ["The euro (sign: €; code: EUR) is the official currency of 19 of the 27 member states ", "Save up to $100 on an eligible iPad and get discounts on iPad accessories and 20% off", "We are a leading academic school with a high level of achievement","This visit can cost anywhere from $35–$250.","The reality is that TV advertising can cost as little as £3 per advert or over 100k. Which is quite a range. So how can an advert cost £3 or 100k?"]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
```

I would need to check how many times the list of symbols: $ % £ € are in the sentences above.

Something that can allow me to have this final dataset

```
Sentences                                                       $        %       £      €
0   The euro (sign: €; code: EUR) is the official ...           0        0       0      1
1   Save up to $100 on an eligible iPad and get di...           1        1       0      0
2   We are a leading academic school with a high l...           0        0       0      0           
3   "This visit can cost anywhere from $35–$250.                2        0       0      0
4   The reality is that TV advertising can cost as..            0        0       2      0
```

I have tried to think on how to create this table and I split the problem into two parts: the first is in counting the occurrence of symbols in each sentence; then explode the dataset, using `explode()`.
However I have some doubt on how to associate to each symbol its occurrence. The problem is that I would need something like this first:

```
Sentences                                                        Symb  
The euro (sign: €; code: EUR) is the official ...            {$:0,%:0, £:0, €:1}
Save up to $100 on an eligible iPad and get di...            {$:1,%:1, £:0, €:1}
We are a leading academic school with a high l...            {$:0,%:0, £:0, €:0}
"This visit can cost anywhere from $35–$250.                 {$:2,%:0, £:0, €:1}
The reality is that TV advertising can cost as..             {$:0,%:0, £:2, €:0}
```

I hope someone of you can give me some advice on it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try and dummify (*although this is not exactly dummies but counts*) relevant columns using `str.findall`, `series.explode` and then `pd.crosstab`

```
import re
find = ['$','%','£','€']
s = df['Text'].str.findall('|'.join([re.escape(i) for i in find])).explode()
out = df.join(pd.crosstab(s.index,s).reindex(df.index,fill_value=0))
```

---

```
print(out)
                                                Text  $  %  £  €
0  The euro (sign: €; code: EUR) is the official ...  0  0  0  1
1  Save up to $100 on an eligible iPad and get di...  1  1  0  0
2  We are a leading academic school with a high l...  0  0  0  0
3        This visit can cost anywhere from $35–$250.  2  0  0  0
4  The reality is that TV advertising can cost as...  0  0  2  0
```

Comment: Thank you so much @anky.

Answer (score 1):

This should do the job for you:

```
df['$'] = df.Text.str.count('$')
df['%'] = df.Text.str.count('%')
df['£'] = df.Text.str.count('£')
df['€'] = df.Text.str.count('€')
```

Comment: Unfortunately I am getting this error: `KeyError: "None of [Index(['$', '%', '£', '€'], dtype='object')] are in the [columns]"`